# Change next item background color in adapter on click of current item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to change the color of the next item of `RecyclerView` on click of current item button from the adapter.
My code is like :

```
holder.pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.pick.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
            editStatus(studentrouteList.get(position).getId(),"2");
            holder.waittime.setText("done!");

         holder.itemstudent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bee180"));
            int currentpos =holder.getAdapterPosition();
            int oldpos = holder.getOldPosition();
            Log.e("", String.valueOf("new pos : "+ currentpos + "old pos : "+ oldpos));
            Constant.pos = currentpos + 1;
            int newpos = position+1;
            if(studentrouteList.get(position + 1).getStatus().equals("0")) {
           holder.itemstudent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next_pickup); // here change current item view ... Need next item to change
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is easy you can do  it with two different ways.

```html
// position of next updated item which we need to update background
updatedPositionToChangeBgColor = -1
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Log.d("onBindViewHolder called ","Adapter");
    if(updatedPositionToChangeBgColor == position) {
        holder.itembackground.setColor("#000000");
    } else {
        // do nothing   
    }
    holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              //update position of next item and call notifyItemChanged to tell adapter it need to recreate next item again  
              updatedPositionToChangeBgColor = position + 1;
              notifyItemChanged(updatedPositionToChangeBgColor);
         }
    });

}
```

Second Way is again same but from Activity class or model call you do or you can use interface to update position and call `notifyItemChanged(updatedPositionToChangeBgColor);` to tell Adapter to re-create that item. And all set
Good to go.
Thanks

Comment: if you got answer, please upvote so future Help seeker can also take advantage like u :D

Comment: downvoter can u please tell me what i did wrong ? my answer is wrong or code is not working? please considered comment while downvoting